# Derivative of the functional partition function relating to non-linear sigma model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, lagrangian-formalism, partition-function

On the page of 457 of *condensed matter field theory* by Altand and Simons, the authors give the partition function 
$$Z = \int Dg e^{-S[g]},$$ 
where
$$
S[g] = \frac{1}{\lambda}\int{d^dr\; \textrm{tr}[\nabla g\nabla g^{-1}]}.
$$
directly without any hint. This partition function relates to the nonlinear sigma model. I just wonder how can I derivative it exactly? Any suggestion?

Comment: Take derivative with respect to what?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus: Hi, maybe you can ask Altland and Simons.      Just for fun.         Here, $g\in G$ takes values in some compat Lie group $G$, and  so on... may be you can see their book for more details.

Comment: Atland and Simons haven't asked this question. And don't be rude.

Comment: I think OP wants a derivat*ion* of the non-linear sigma model, not a derivat*ive*... This is done in an exercice in the Altland and Simons book, check the index about non-linear sigma model, you will find the page (p. 326 seems to be the one on my second edition ...) answering your question. Then you may come back here with a more precise question if you have some :-)